# I was having a bath with my glasses wore/wearing?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I want say a sentence like: I was having a bath with my glasses **wore/wearing**

I've definitely come cross similar structure like this, with my stuff + past simple(or perhaps past participle). Hopefully I've articulated my thought clearly enough.

Comment: You say you have definitely come across similar structures. I can't think of any with the past simple following the noun in a _with_ prepositional phrase. But a past or present participle is possible. In that case, however, the participles will modify the noun they follow, not (as in your case) the subject of the sentence. For example, _I was having a bath with my glasses perched on my head_ or _I was having a bath with my glasses steaming up the whole time_.

Comment: @Shoe hh apparently something went wrong with my memory, thanks for you examples.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence can be simplified to

> I was having a bath with my glasses on.

Or rearranged as

> I was having a bath while wearing my glasses.

Comment: They're good examples and remind me of some other things, can I also ask you how do you say, like, those people are riding a motorbike with noisy music playing on, or perhaps along? Is this sentence acceptable?

Comment: That's a different question, and this sentence should be "...with noisy music playing."

Comment: In this case there's no preposition is needed?

Comment: @Angyang *With* is a preposition.